# what happens when you set transform.position in Unity?

Tags: unity

Unity has both `transform.position`and`transform.localPosition`.
When I do `transform.position.x += 3f;` does unity automatically update transform.localposition?
and vice versa?

Why can I not see this when I go to the definition of `transform.position` in VS?

Comment: What do your experiments tell you when you change `position` then read `localPosition` or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `transform.position` in Unity, the engine automatically calculates the corresponding local position the object needs relative to its parent to arrive at that location, and sets its local position there.

When you set `transform.localPosition`, the local position is updated directly. Subsequent attempts to read `transform.position` or use any of the `Transform`'s transformation methods will use this new local position - in addition to any parent transforms.

(Don't underestimate your power to find these things out through your own testing - a short script that sets `position` or `localPosition` and prints the values of both before and after would have answered most of your question, much faster than waiting for a stranger to reply here!)

In C# code, this would look something like this:

```
public Vector3 position {
    get {
        if (parent == null)
            return localPosition;

        return parent.TransformPoint(localPosition);
    }

    set {
        if (parent == null)
             localPosition = value;
        else
             localPosition = parent.InverseTransformPoint(value);
        hasChanged = true;
    }
}
```

The reason you don't see this implementation in Visual Studio is likely because this isn't implemented in managed C# code, but in the engine's underlying C++ code, compiled down to a native binary, to which the C# representation just provides a wrapper.

Comment: You're right I thought about doing my own testing and I could have seen the updates to transform but it would still leave me wonder why I can't see this and why this is so obscure. I searched google and I found nothing on this. It's not clear when I go to the definition either, there's only a property declaration but no definition